# MatchPattern in TFS build definition causing MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am currently updating our build definition in TFS, and I need to find the project that needs to be built in our solution. This is done by adding a file to the project and using it as a flag. Currently, this is done like so:

```
<mtbwa:FindMatchingFiles 
       DisplayName="Find ClickOnce Projects" 
       sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FindMatchingFiles_2" 
       MatchPattern="[String.Format(&quot;{0}\**\ProjectToBuild.txt&quot;, Path.GetDirectoryName(localProject))]" 
       Result="[ClickOnceFlags]" />
```

Where we have different flags in different projects and different build template files for different builds. I want to remove "ProjectToBuild.txt" from the MatchPattern property and add a variable called FlagName, which is set when defining a build definition. That way, we use the same build template file for multiple build definitions.

This is the result:

```
<mtbwa:FindMatchingFiles 
       DisplayName="Find ClickOnce Projects" 
       sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FindMatchingFiles_2" 
       MatchPattern="[String.Format(&quot;{0}\**\{1}&quot;, Path.GetDirectoryName(localProject), FlagFileName)]" 
       Result="[ClickOnceFlags]" />
```

I changed the file name in the string format to {1}, and added a variable called FlagFileName to the build template file.

```
<x:Property Name="FlagFileName" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
```

To test this, I simply set the FlagFileName variable to "ProjectToBuild.txt", and tried running the build, expecting the same results as before. But instead it could not complete the build, citing

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
```

Can any one advise me what went wrong here?

Comment: What's the detail value in ProjectToBuild.txt? Share your build process template file on the OneDrive, I will make a test to check it.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? If not, could you share your build process template file on the OneDrive?

Comment: Hey starain, I'm sorry but I'm not allowed to post the build file here. We did end up fixing the error though, but it did not have anything to do with the above command, it had something to do with one of the programs we used under our build process did not respond as it should when running as a test build. Thats why we didn't catch it at first :)

Comment: You can post it as answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up fixing the error, but it did not have anything to do with the above command, it had something to do with one of the programs we used under our build process did not respond as it should when running as a test build.

To be more precise, we were attempting to test a deployment method which utilized a custom made program we had built. We had not checked that program, and it actually used that flag to determine the program version (this was only a problem when using the test build). This led to an inconsistant version, which led to a problem further down the chain.